# How to control the number of downloads via Amazon Cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way to create a CloudFront signed url that limits the number of times that a file can be downloaded?

According to this post [Controlling number of downloads on Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062136/controlling-number-of-downloads-on-amazon-s3), you can get the number of file downloads via the cloudfront api (but it cant find any reference to this on the amazon site)

Has anyone managed to achieve this via CloudFront?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with CloudFront you can serve [Private Content](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html).

Basically you can protect your content in two ways:

- Require that your users use special CloudFront signed URLs to access your content, not the standard CloudFront public URLs.
- Require that your users access your Amazon S3 content using CloudFront URLs, not Amazon S3 URLs.

When you create signed URLs for your objects, you can specify:

- An ending date and time, after which the URL is no longer valid.
- (Optional) The date and time that the URL becomes valid.
- (Optional) The IP address or range of addresses of the computers that can be used to access your content.